# Google Dataflow stalled after BigQuery outage

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Google Dataflow Job running. The dataflow job is reading messages from Pub/Sub, enrich it and write the enriched data into BigQuery.

Dataflow was processing approximately 5000 messages per second. I am using 20 workers to run the dataflow job.

Yesterday it seems there was a BigQuery outage. So writing the data in BigQuery part failed. After some time, my dataflow stopped working. 
I see 1000 errors like below

```
  (7dd47a65ad656a43): Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The project xx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx has not enabled BigQuery.",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "The project xx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx has not enabled BigQuery.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryTableInserter.insertAll(BigQueryTableInserter.java:285)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryTableInserter.insertAll(BigQueryTableInserter.java:175)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$StreamingWriteFn.flushRows(BigQueryIO.java:2728)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$StreamingWriteFn.finishBundle(BigQueryIO.java:2685)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.finishBundle(DoFnRunnerBase.java:159)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.finishBundle(SimpleParDoFn.java:194)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.finishBundle(ForwardingParDoFn.java:47)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.finish(ParDoOperation.java:65)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:719)
Stack trace truncated. Please see Cloud Logging for the entire trace.
```

Please note that dataflow is not working even the BigQuery started working. I had to restart the dataflow job to make it work.

This causes data loss. Not only at the time of outage, but also until I notice the error and restart dataflow job. Is there a way to configure the retry option so that dataflow job does not go into stale on these cases?

Comment: Do you have a job id?

Comment: Trying to understand here -- is the sequence of events as follows?

1.- pipeline running
2.- outage
3.- restart, observe above failure
4.- subsequent successful restart
?

Or, is the error while running, after outage, before attempting a restart?

Comment: @Pablo Yes I've job Id, but I don't want to add it in SOF

Comment: @rf- Sequence is as follows. 1. Pipeline running. 2. BigQuery outage. 3. Dataflow outage with BQ error. 4. BigQuery back online. 5. Dataflow still outage. 6. Restart Dataflow and it started working, but data loss

Comment: Back to your original question, there is no retry you could tweak here. We were retrying on your behalf. One possibility is that the pipeline accumulated enough state that we couldn't continue processing even after BQ came back -- this could be mitigated by adding workers in some cases. I wouldn't want to speculate too much on this case. Note you could open a support ticket and we could be able to look at the job specifics.

Comment: @rf- It is good that Google Dataflow is trying itself on behalf of me. But AFAIK, the no.of times it should retry should be configurable. In such case, we can configure it as some finite values and there is high chance that pipeline is not going into stale state